# How can my app ask k8s which specific resource-ids were assigned to a deployed pod?

Tags: kubernetes

A few years ago I wrote a device-plugin, and it reacts to AllocateRequests for Intel QAT devices.  Until recently, pods ran under kubevirt.  When a tenant deploys, an AllocateRequest arrives at the plugin, and the plugin reacts as expected.  When the host reboots with running pods that were using QAT resources, the pods restart after a new AllocateRequest arrives at the plugin.

One of the difficulties with the plugin is that we have to try and figure out which pod is responsible for the AllocateRequest being sent.  We need this so we can do other housekeeping related to the pod+QAT devices.  We have a confd side that tells us pod names and deployment state (deployed, configured), and the plugin watches confd for pods that go from configured to deployed, and matches it with the AllocateRequest.  Up to now, this has worked fine.

But now we have added non-kubevirt pod support to our platform, and the non-kubevirt pods  don't always tell our confd interface when they redeploy due to a non-QAT related error.  This results in an AllocateRequest arriving at the plugin for a pod our confd interface indicates is already deployed.  Since we can have zero to 128 pods deployed, it is difficult to deterministically know who the AllocateRequest belongs to.

My first reaction was to try and find a way to get k8s to tell me the resource-ids assigned to the pod using informers.  I added the informer factory, et al, and the following callback:

```
    func AddPod(obj interface{}) {
            pod := obj.(*v1.Pod)
            fmt.Println("Pod all: ", pod)
    }
```

I can see when pods are deployed, and when a pod generates a new AllocateRequest.  I see the QAT reference in the output, but there are no resource-ids.  The QAT piece of the message generated by the above AddPod() looks like:

```
    xx.com/qat: {{15 0} {<nil>" 15 DecimalSI},
```

The QAT device count of 15 is correct, but no resource-ids...  And I need to know the resource-ids for a new short-list of bugs that have cropped up, all related to getting a AllocateRequest I can't match with the pod who caused it to happen.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to use informers, or something like informers, to show
   me the resource-ids assigned to a pod?
2. Since it appears these resource-id assignments are remembered by k8s after a
   reboot, how is k8s serializing them?
3. Can I get to the resource-id assignments anywhere in the k8s logs?

Thanks,

-Donald

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the information given, to provide information regarding your queries,

1. **[I](http://1.Is)s there a way to use informers, or something like informers, to show me the resource-ids assigned to a pod?**

   Unfortunately informers will not be able to do that since the Kubernetes API server will only provide the quantity of the resources assigned but not the specific resource IDs.
2. **Since it appears these resource-id assignments are remembered by k8s after a reboot, how is k8s serializing them?**

   After reboots, Kubernetes doesn’t remember the specific devices you assigned. Rather the kubelet upon restart sees pods assigned then send new Allocate request for these devices. The device plugin and kubelet ensures correct resource assignments but specific serialization is not exposed outside of the kubelet.
3. **Can I get to the resource-id assignments anywhere in the k8s logs?**

   Try increasing the verbosity of logging as it may capture exact details of the allocation. It might be present in the logs depending on how the device plugin and kubelet interact.

Attached are some helpful links for your use case.[1][2][3]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

[2] https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.0/tools/cache

[3] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/